# After RedirectToAction no View displays

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a Login Page.After validation i redirect to the required page.It redirects but No

View appers rather it display the previous Login page View.

here is my Javascript COde

```
    function abc() {
        var email = document.forms["MyForm"]["Email"].value;
        var password = document.forms["MyForm"]["Password"].value;
        if (email.length == 0 || password.length == 0) {
            alert("Email and Password Field Required");
            return false;
        }
        else {


            $.ajax({
                 url: $("#MyForm").attr('action'),
                type: $("#MyForm").attr('method'),
                data: $("#MyForm").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                     alert("Invalid Email or Password");
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is the controller
 [HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult UserLogin(Models.UserModel selectedDocuments)

    {                                  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            long AdminID = IsValid(selectedDocuments.Email, selectedDocuments.Password);
            if (AdminID != 0)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(selectedDocuments.Email, false);
                if (RoleID == 1)
                {
                    Session["SystemAdmin"] = true;
                    Session["AdminID"] = AdminID;
                    return RedirectToAction("ClubInfo", "Admin");
                }
                if (RoleID == 2)
                {
                    Session["ClubAdmin"] = true;
                    Session["AdminID"] = AdminID;
                    return RedirectToAction("ClubInfo", "ClubAdmin");
                }
                if (RoleID == 3)
                {
                    Session["NewsAdmin"] = true;
                    Session["AdminID"] = AdminID;
                    return RedirectToAction("ClubInfo", "NewsAdmin");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Data Is Incorrect.");

            }
        }
        return Json(new { selectedDocuments = "Whatever you want to send" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

SomeBody help me how i will do it successfully.

Comment: it is ajax call it will return the view html in repsonse of ajax call

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad would you plz help me with code that ho to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As form is posted via ajax call view will be returned as response of ajax call and user will not be able to view the redirected view.

Instead of `reutrn RedirectToAction()` use  `return Json` and redirect from client side:

```
return Json(new 
               { 
                RedirectUrl= Url.Action("ClubInfo", "Admin")
               }
               ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and in success function of ajax:

```
success: function (data) {
                     window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

i do it by changing redirect

return Json(Url.Action("ClubInfo", "Admin"));

and in javascript

```
                $.ajax({

                 url: $("#MyForm").attr('action'),
                type: $("#MyForm").attr('method'),
                data: $("#MyForm").serialize(),
                success: function (result) {

                        window.location.href = result;


                },
                error:function ()
               {
                 alert("Invalid Email or password");
               }
            });
```